# Flick a Rectangle with the Canvas in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to hold mousedown on a rectangle, move in a direction, let go, and upon release have the rectangle be 
"flicked" towards the appropriate direction. I want to accomplish something like this:

[How do I flick a DIV and have it move in the right direction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827916/how-do-i-flick-a-div-and-have-it-move-in-the-right-direction)

but with a rectangle drawn in the HTML5 Canvas. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

With the canvas, you'll want to use the same technique as in that post, except using multiple frames and erasing/drawing the rectangle each frame.  Pseudocode:

```
setTimeout(1000/30, function () {
  canvas.erase()
  rect.update_position()
  canvas.drawRect(rect)
})
```

Alternately, you can use a physics engine like Box2dWeb to do all kinds of stuff like  'flicking' - http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/